# Issue with deleting blank rows

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a limit to certain functions

I'm using

```
Worksheet.Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

which works fine when I was testing, however the live data I'm trying to process has 27k rows and when I use this function, it doesn't delete the blank rows, it deletes everything.

I can use a for loop to check rows individually(but this is slow and not as elegant a solution)

Can anyone help please?

Comment: So are you trying to delete blank rows or blank cells? It looks like you want to delete the entire row wherever a cell in the first column is blank.

Comment: Try `Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Entirerow.Delete`

Comment: Hi,sorry this was so long ago, but yes I was trying to delete the entire row when first column is blank

Thanks for the answer